Solucionar error detectado desde PageSpeed Insights
He estado chequeando la web desde PageSpeed Insights y me da este tipo de error y no se como solucionarlo:
/script.js:1:0(www.dominio.es)
    

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

https://www.dominio.es:502:19
    

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED

La carga de la página aparentemente carga bien, no se ven fallos que se vean visualmente ¿no sé si podríais indicarme como solucionarlo?

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < en /script.js:
Verifica que script.js esté disponible y se sirva como JavaScript. Accede directamente al archivo en el navegador para asegurarte de que no devuelve HTML.
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/' failed:
Elimina cualquier referencia a WebSocket (ws://localhost:35729/) que se esté cargando en el entorno de producción, ya que es solo para desarrollo.
